# Move clustered MSMQ storage location

Tags: cluster, msmq

We have a two-node active/passive Windows 2003 cluster running MSMQ among other things. Windows picked the Quorum drive to store the queue messages, but this drive has VERY limited disk space. How can we change the location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MSMQ location is based on the disk resource you choose when you set up MSMQ as a cluster service. In my case, we have 4 disks in a single resource. According to our MS tech, this isn't a supported configuration.

The solution is to set up the disks as individual cluster resources. Then, we can choose the specific disk we want when we set up MSMQ.

Comment: To become separate resources, each disk must present as a unique LUN to the OS, not just a partition on a single large RAID array.

Answer (score 1):

There is one and only one way to move the storage directory for MSMQ. It cannot be done in a scripted manner; it can only be done manually.

- Go to the computer management MMC
- Expand the "Services and Applications" node
- Right click "Message Queuing" and select "properties"
- Go to the storage tab and modify the location.

The MMC utility does the following:

1. Makes sure the new target is valid (meaning, not a network share but a local disk).
2. Makes the directory tree
3. Sets proper permissions
4. Moves the data

[Official reference material.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2009/02/09/changing-the-msmq-storage-location.aspx)

Comment: Your article also says "Note - It is not supported to change the locations for a clustered MSMQ resource and no UI is available to allow you to do this."

Comment: Ah, yes. The cluster part of the equation is important.

Comment: updated link: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/johnbreakwell/changing-the-msmq-storage-location